# Llamo a una activity desde un fragment y no se ejecuta

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Tengo un problema con una app que estoy desarrollando, no es muy complicada, resulta que desde un **Fragment** trato de ejecutar una *activity* utilizando un botón, no hay errores de compilación, pero cuando pincho un botón la *activity*  correspondiente no se ejecuta, sale de la aplicación y muestra el siguiente error `Unfortunately has stopped`.

A continuación el código del fragment.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link PresentacionFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link PresentacionFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class PresentacionFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public PresentacionFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment AcercadeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PresentacionFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PresentacionFragment fragment = new PresentacionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString( ARG_PARAM1, param1 );
        args.putString( ARG_PARAM2, param2 );
        fragment.setArguments( args );
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString( ARG_PARAM1 );
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString( ARG_PARAM2 );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle( "Inicio..." );
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_presentacion, container, false );
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction( uri );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach( context );
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException( context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener" );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public void clickBoton(View view) {
         switch (view.getId()){
             case R.id.btn_areal:
                 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AudioRealActivity.class);
                 getActivity().startActivity(i);
                 break;
             case R.id.btn_sitiow:
                 Intent j = new Intent(getActivity(), NoticiasActivity.class);
                 getActivity().startActivity(j);
                 break;
             case R.id.btn_pods:
                 Intent k = new Intent(getActivity(), InvooxActivity.class);
                 getActivity().startActivity(k);
                 break;
         }
    }



    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }



}
```

> En el diseño del layout correspondiente se obtiene el siguiente código del xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PresentacionFragment">


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo85rcm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/logo85rcm" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rcmdia2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/rcmdia" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"

        android:gravity="left|start"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_areal"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:onClick="clickBoton"
        android:text="Audio Real"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sitiow"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_areal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:onClick="clickBoton"
        android:text="Sitio web" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_pods"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_areal"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:onClick="clickBoton"
        android:text="PodCast" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

> Al revisar el log, encuentro el siguiente error:
> **Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton**

> Lo que necesito es que se ejecute la activity correspondiente al botón seleccionado. Gracias

> Más del Logcat, es lo que sale de color rojo.
>
> > 

05-20 01:44:26.282 2399-2399/cu.radiociudaddelmar.linor.rcmapk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: cu.radiociudaddelmar.linor.rcmapk, PID: 2399
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method daleClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btn_areal'
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

> **Recordar que estoy haciendo la llamada desde un fragment, no desde una Activity**.
> Gracias

Comment: Agrega por favor la parte del Logcat donde dice "Caused by". Al ver tu código te puedo asegurar que el problema es en la Activity que tratas de abrir.

Answer (score 0):

> Hola.
> El problema se resuelve poniendo el OnClick en la clase padre, es decir en la MainActivity.